# Using Highland in combination with node-client

Tags: highland.js, heroku-api

I'm trying to use [highland](http://highlandjs.org) in combination with the [heroku-client](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client). But internally in the heroku client it uses `this`, even if I try to `bind` to bind this, the function gives and error message where there is a refrance to `this` I'm not able to get it to work.

Right no the code looks like this

```
const Heroku = require('heroku-client');
const hl = require('highland');
var hk = new Heroku({
  token: process.env.HEROKU_API_TOKEN
});
var list = hl.wrapCallback(hk.apps().list.bind(hk));
list().toArray((a) => 'console.log(a)')
```

So this code snippet fails with the following error message:

```
...node_modules/heroku-client/lib/resourceBuilder.js:35
if (this.params.length !== pathParams.length) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo! :-)

You're binding to `hk` and not what `hk.apps()` return, which is what the `list` function depends on (it's a member of what `hk.apps()` returns)

Try this:

```
const Heroku = require('heroku-client');
const hl = require('highland');
const hk = new Heroku({
  token: process.env.HEROKU_API_TOKEN
});
const hkApps = hk.apps();
const list = hl.wrapCallback(hkApps.list.bind(hkApps));
list().toArray((a) => 'console.log(a)')
```

Comment: This works. The only thing to mention is the copy paste from my question where I do `(a) => 'console.log(a)'` and not `(a) => console.log(a)`.